# Computing the covariance between residuals

Tags: r, linear-model, residuals

I'm doing some self-studying of some modules about using R in linear regression. We were given data for a multiple linear model with two independent variables , $y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon ∼ N(0,2)$:

```
y        x1  x2
-3.09   3.6 4.4
-2.57   4.2 6.2
-6.19   3.2 6.0
-7.21   5.0 4.3
-0.97   5.3 4.6
-5.70   3.1 3.8
-4.40   5.7 4.9
-4.75   4.2 5.1
-2.21   4.7 5.3
-4.95   4.4 6.0
-7.61   2.5 5.7
-6.70   3.2 6.0
-1.65   4.7 4.5
-2.50   4.1 4.9
```

We were first asked to compute the variance of the first residual. I obtained 3.207 (which turned out to be the correct value) after doing the following in R:

```
 mod <- lm(y~x1+x2)
 h <- hatvalues(mod)
 var_e1 = 4 * (1 - h[[1]])
```

Then we were asked to obtain covariance between the first and third residual. The answer given to us was -0.1449218, however, I'm stumped about how this is obtained. Having no idea how to start computing this, what's the intuition behind computing the covariance between residuals?

Comment: Are you referring to [autocovariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,of%20the%20process%20in%20question.)?

Comment: @Dayne I'm not sure if it's that what is being asked since the modules don't even mention time series. The exact wording is "What is the covariance between the first and third residual?".

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to confirm. I have posted an answer. Hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Assume model is:

$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2I)$

The residuals, $\hat{\epsilon_i}$ are estimates of true errors, $\epsilon_i$

The are related to each other by the **residual-maker matrix**, $M \equiv I-P=I-X(X'X)^{-1}X'$

Therefore,

$$Var(\hat{\epsilon})=Var(My)=MVar(y)M'=\sigma^2MM'$$

Since $M$ is idempotent and symmetric this becomes:

$$Var(\hat{\epsilon})=\sigma^2M$$

So $Cov(\hat{\epsilon_1},\hat{\epsilon_3})=\sigma^2m_{13}=\sigma^2m_{31}$, where $m_{ij}$ is element of Matrix $M$ corresponding to row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: which is equal to the same element of the hat matrix